# Which phone number is shared by Apple Pay in a dual SIM iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sim, apple-pay, esim

When adding a card to Apple Pay, it says that your phone number may be shared with the bank who emitted your card. But in the case of a dual SIM phone which number is shared? If you have a personal phone number and another one, can you choose which one will be shared with the bank?
Have anyone a personal experience with a dual SIM phone and Apple Pay?

Comment: I’ll assume you aren’t talking about the Apple Card and you are adding a third party card to Apple Pay wallet.

Comment: @bmike yes, correct, it’s not the Apple Card, but a third party

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Apple Pay uses a billing address and not a mobile phone. Your AppleID can have any phone you want, so either or none would get pre-filled into a form that asks for a phone.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204506
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205630

I would get your Apple ID correct with the number you prefer in case that is part of the messages activation process. You can see that in the settings app under **iCloud** then **Name, Phone Numbers, Email**. Also check under messages, under send and receive to select one, both or none of your mobile numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don’t get how it’s ‘neither’ when Wallet app says that it may share a phone number (and other info) with the bank?

Comment: Some banks require a phone call to activate this. What does your bank say, @WhoAmI ?